# How to get a value of setting "gps location enabled" in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-mobile-gps

While my app is working - I need to check, that GPS-location is on.
I DO NOT need any complex things with statusChanged and other - just check a value of setting.

If that setting is off - I must stop execute current operation. I got one method, which called every time, when user execute operation. And I wanna place check rule there. So - it must be fast and cheap.

Is there any human way? Without keeping GPSWatcher ON all the time, and check his last status. I must care about battery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();

if (geolocator.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.Disabled)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but only for WP8. WP7 is out.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation

```
var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
switch (accessStatus)
{
case GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed:

    break;

case GeolocationAccessStatus.Denied:
    _
    break;

case GeolocationAccessStatus.Unspecified:


    break;
}
```